# How to add a column to pyspark dataframe using when condition all from different dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am actually trying to convert the following sql to pyspark.

```
   UPDATE table_a a, table_b b
   SET a.flag=1
   WHERE 
   (
    b.NOD=1
    OR
    (b.flag_3=1 AND b.flag_1=0 AND b.testingSold=0)
   ) 
   AND b.uuid=a.uuid
```

I Tried the following code but its not working :

```
   table_a = table_a.withColumn("flag", F.when((table_b.NOD ==1) | (table_b.flag_3 == 1) & (table_b.flag_1==0) & table_a.uuid == table_b.uuid), F.lit(1))
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
table_a.join(table_b, table_a.uuid == table_b.uuid).withColumn("flag", F.when((table_b.NOD ==1) | ((table_b.flag_3 == 1) & (table_b.flag_1==0) & (table_b.testingSold == 0),  F.lit(1)))
```

Comment: wont all the columns of table_b also be visible in this case?

Comment: I have no use with any of table_b columns except in condition statements

Comment: yes all columns of table_b would be visible too. If you don't need columns of table_b after the logic, then you can simply drop those columns :)